# Excel VBA - Check if ANY cell used by macro has been updated, if so rerun macro. Maintain formatting

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have an Excel workbook which contains lists of sales leads in worksheets, separated out by alphabet (worksheet 'A' contains all leads that start with 'A'). I run the following macro on a separate worksheet to combine all these sheets into one master sheet (code found [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win002.htm)).

**GOAL:** When I change a cell in a worksheet (say worksheet A), I want this to update on the master sheet where my macro is being run. I assume I need to just rerun the macro whenever one of these cells is changed. Is there a way to automatically detect changes in any of the data being utilized by the macro and then triggering it to rerun?

I have found solutions on how to do this to a range of cells or specific cell, but not every cell in a range of worksheets.

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)

        'Fill in the range that you want to copy
        Set CopyRng = sh.UsedRange

        'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
        If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
            GoTo ExitTheSub
        End If

        'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
        'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

        'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "M").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

    End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

It would be great if it maintained formatting. The cells get resized every time I rerun the macro.

Comment: Use a WorkBook_SheetChange gauging Target against a union of the cells that affect change on each worksheet.

Comment: btw, there is no formatting to 'maintain'. It appears you delete the 'master' worksheet and recreate it. You cannot maintain something that you delete. Code the recreation of the formatting or simply clear the values from the 'master' worksheet and append the blank worksheet with the new values.